# How do I add a desktop shortcut in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-shortcut

Some installers don’t bother creating a desktop shortcut. Obviously I can find the application from the Start button.

I should have thought there must be a simple way of creating a desktop shortcut from the start menu or from the task bar. Dragging & Dropping doesn’t do the job and neither does right-click.

I know I can find the original location of the application, and make a shortcut from there, but is there a simple way to create a shortcut from either the start menu or the task bar?

To clarify, there doesn’t appear to be an option to create a shortcut when I find the application:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Dragging & Dropping doesn’t do the job..."? I can drag & drop from the start menu to the desktop and it creates a shortcut.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I can’t. I have tried with the left and right mouse buttons. I have tried it at home and in the training room.

Comment: Right click on App, More options, Folder, Make shortcut. I do this once in a while so it is certainly very simple for just occasionally.. Same way in Windows 11.

Comment: Right click on desktop, click new, select shortcut, type filepath to the file you want add shortcut to, type shortcut name, click ok, done.

Comment: Right click the app > Show File Location. Now copy the shortcut from the explorer window that opens to your desktop.

Comment: @Manngo Did you want to create this shortcut on your Desktop with a vbscript ? if yes i will post you an answser for doing that !

Answer (score 1):

For Desktop apps, you can open Explorer, click in the Address bar, and type either:

- `shell:Programs`
- `shell:Common Programs`

The first opens the folder of Start Menu shortcuts unique to your user profile, THe second opens the folder of Start Menu shortcut common to all users on your computer.

[image]

Locate the desired program, right-click, and select `Send to > Desktop (Create shortcut)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with all apps installed via Windows store. You can no longer find "open file location" in the menu, which will take you to the exe file. From there you can create a shortcut.

[image]

The workaround is a 2 step process.

1. Search for the program in start menu, right click and pin to start menu.
2. Drag the icon from the start menu to the desktop, you will see a "Link overlay" if you are doing it correctly.

[image]